# What exceptions should I handle

Tags: c#, .net, exception, design-patterns, try-catch

I have the below code:

```
        public void OpenFile(string FileName)
        {
            if (FileName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName", "OpenFile: Filename is null");


            List<int> readItems = new List<int>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                string line;
                int batchItem;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(line, out batchItem))
                    {
                        readItems.Add(batchItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            CurrrentFile = FileName;
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileName);
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                TextWriter = f.AppendText();
                TextWriter.AutoFlush = true;
            }

            if (readItems.Count > 0)
                FileOpened(readItems);


        }
```

I am trying to detect possible problems eg/ Filename is null.

In the class that catches and logs exceptions I obviously have a `catch(ArgumentNullException ex)`

Should I also be catching possible exceptions thrown by the `StreamReader` constructor and `FileInfo` constructor?

I know that sounds silly but I wondered whether I should have explicit catches for the exceptions I'm throwing and then a general exception catch whether it be a `catch(Exception ex)` or have a try catch around the above code and rethrow a custom exception. Otherwise my try/catch block has about 12 separate catch statements!

Comment: Obligatory [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) to Eric Lippert's article about the different kinds of exceptions and the proper way to handle them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But in the scenario of StreamReader/FileInfo there's not a great deal I can do. If I check myself that a filename is invalid I would throw the exception myself and have a catch for it so I'm not preventing anything really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you follow a few simple rules you can drastically simplify your Exception Handling code.

**1. Only catch and handle exceptions you can actually *do* something about**

If you can't actually recover from an exception, then you shouldn't catch it at all. Let the exception bubble up to the highest possible point (usually the User Interface).

When you do catch exceptions you should catch very specific exceptions, and avoid generic exception handling if at all possible.

```
try
{
   DoSomeStuff();
}
catch(HolyCrapItBlewedUpException ex)
{
   RecoverFromExplosion();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //I really have no idea what happened, and I can't do
   // anything about it, but I'm going to catch the
   // exception anyway cause it makes me feel better
}
```

There are ***cough*** exceptions to the rule above, but that brings us to our second rule.

**2. Only use generic exception handling for logging, and implementation hiding**

Since you should be letting your exceptions bubble all the way up to the highest layer, anything that makes it to the top is a bug. At that point, you should be logging that exception and presenting some friendly message to the user.

```
try
{
   DoSomeStuff();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //At this point it's a bug... we need to squash it!
   LogException(ex);
   ShowUserRecoveryOptions();
}
```

Another place you might want to do this is in order to maintain a contract for an API, and hide implementation details. If the end user is calling a method, they may not need to know every possible problem that occurred, only that it didn't work.

```
public void MakeMeASandwich()
{
   try
   {
      MakeCallerASandwich();
   }
   catch(SecurityException ex)
   {
      //It's still best to distinguish between certain exceptions
      // as long as it makes sense to the caller.
      throw new NoIWillNotMakeYouASandwichException(ex);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw new SorryICantMakeYouASandwichException(ex);
   }
}
```

**3. Avoid Exceptions Like The Plague!**

Exceptions should be, well... exceptional! In most instances you should be able to avoid exceptions by simply coding for them in advance. A real exception should represent something you couldn't predict would happen. A simple example is checking for the existence of a file.

```
try
{
   File.Open("blah.txt");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
   File.Create("blah.txt");
}
```

In that example, I knew it was possible the file would not exist... so I should have written code to make sure that case *almost* never happens.

```
var fileName = "blah.txt";

if(!File.Exists(fileName))
   File.Create(fileName);

File.Open(fileName);
```

Now, it is still possible for a `FileNotFoundException` to be thrown here, but how would we handle it? Clearly this code can no longer do anything about it since something truly **EXCEPTIONAL** happened. We can let the exception bubble up to the next layer since there is nothing meaningful we can do here.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure to have your general exception viz SystemException/ApplicationException/Exception catch clause to be at the last. So prepare for obvious. In your case SecurityException, FileNotFound, PathNotFound, etc exceptions. Please check the MSDN document for those APIs and what all kinds of exceptions do they throw.

The problem in making a generic exception is youll never know what actually is the problem, even FxCop gives warning for this. No problem if your catch clauses are more, but just make sure you split and catch the exceptions. For example, if our opening 2 files in diffirent occasions, then catch each of them seperately rather than one.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I also be catching possible exceptions thrown by the
>   StreamReader constructor and FileInfo constructor?

To keep it short: can you do something reasonable knowing that those exceptions were thrown? If yes, catch them and do it. If not, let it break.

Answer (score 0):

use try catch
If there is an error u can catch it in the catch section. Use Specific exception first and generic exception later.